# Create tar.gz archive and add all files and folders without parent folder

Tags: linux, tar

For example i have folder "admin" which contains folder "1" and two php files "index.php" and "page.php". I try to use `tar -zcvf admin.tar.gz admin` and got admin.tar.gz archive. If i open this archive, i can see archive contains "admin" folder and inside this directory is folder "1" and two php files.

I want to create tar.gz archive with all files and folders, but without parent folder. Create archive and it contains only folder "1" and two php files. How i can do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `-C` option:

```
tar -C admin -zcvf admin.tar.gz .
```

See `man tar`

```
-C, --directory=DIR
   Change to DIR before performing any operations.
   This option is order-sensitive, i.e. it affects all options that follow.
```